# Avoiding Duplicate Data in DB (for use with Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, duplicate-data

I have five tables that I am trying to get to work nicely together but may need some help.

I have three main tables:

- accounts
- members
- and roles.

With two join tables

- account_members
- and account_member_roles.

The **accounts** and **members** table are joined by **account_members** (fk account_id and member_id) table.

The other 2 tables are the problem (**roles** and **account_member_roles**).

A member of an account can have more than one role and I have the **account_member_roles** (fk account_member_id and role_id) table joining the **account_members** join table and the **roles** table.

That seems logical but can you have a relationship with a join table? What I'd like to be able to do is when creaeting an account, for instance, I would like **@account.save** to include the roles and update the **account_member_roles** table neatly ..... but through the **account_members** join table.

I've tried .....

```
accept_nested_attributes_for :members, :account_member_roles
```

in the account.rb but I get .....

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasManyReflection (Cannot modify association 'Account#account_member_roles' because the source reflection class 'AccountMemberRole' is associated to 'AccountMember' via :has_many.)
```

upon trying to save a record.

Any advice on how I should approach this?

CIA

-ants

Comment: You have described how you are solving a problem, but you have not described which problem you are trying to solve. @Sleepycat (below) described a problem. Is that the one you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading this correctly you have:

accounts habtm members

members habtm accounts

members has_many roles

If that is accurate you just need a join table between accounts and members and then just a regular FK between members and roles. @account.members and @account.members.roles would both give you access to the attributes you need and @account.save should save the whole mess without a fuss.

I am not sure what compels you to have that account_members_roles table. I don't if Rails can handle that. I know I sure can't. :)

Comment: I second this solution, if Sleepycat described the right problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a read here:
http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/4/17/join-models-not-proxy-collections

> The main difference between a simple
>   has_and_belongs_to_many join table and
>   a has_many :through join model is that
>   the join model can have attributes
>   other than the foreign keys for the
>   records it is joining. In fact, if you
>   didn't have those other attributes you
>   probably wouldn't use a join model and
>   would settle for a join table.

So it seems that you want to use has_many :through and you would be set.

Comment: I am using has_many :thorugh. Maybe the problem is that the primary key for the join *model* account_members hasn't been created before trying to create the join *model* account_member_roles. This seems to be my real question, can I have join models associated with each other?

Comment: I don't see why not, as long as you can handle the complexity :)